# How to make a search filter with multiple slectboxes using isotope.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want a search filter like [here](https://kleverkid.in/).

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest creating a form (obviously), let the user fill it in and send the variables concluded from that form into a query like `SELECT [needed data columns] FROM table(s) WHERE param1 = form-input1, param2 = form-input2 etc...` to fetch the needed data from your database.

Comment: is there any fiddle i have to make a search filter like kleverkid has

Comment: @adarshaJha have you tried to do find this out by yourself? if so, could you show us what you did? Stack Overflow is meant to help people, not to do something for  them, maybe read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask